# Command Prompt: Why do I get “cannot find the path specified” when I move a folder (with contents) from the desktop to a new directory?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

```
move C:\%USERNAME%\Desktop\TZClock C:\%USERNAME%\Start Menu\Programs\TZClock
```

I keep getting system cannot find the path specified. But I can navigate to it.
Does `MOVE` only work on files?

Comment: You'll also get this error if the destination *parent* directory does not exist. So if the `C:\%USERNAME%\Start Menu\Programs` folder does not exist, you won't be able to move the `TZClock` folder into it.

Answer (score 21):

Under Windows XP, it would be thus:

```
move "c:\documents and settings\%USERNAME%\desktop\TZClock" "C:\documents and settings\%USERNAME%\Start Menu\Programs\TZClock"
```

On Windows 7, it is the following (though I'm not in a position to test this right now):

```
move "c:\users\%USERNAME%\desktop\TZClock" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\TZClock"
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight on how to do it on XP. I intend to make a version for it too. Im on Win7.

Comment: Are you sure you didn’t mean to use `%USERPROFILE%` and only write code once rather than per OS?

Comment: Oh, I see, the `Start Menu` isn’t under `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows` on XP. Anyway, you probably want to use `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` rather than the user-global `%PROGRAMDATA%` directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to move more than one directory using wildcard, you can use [`FOR /D`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) command.
Type this in command-line (don't forget to replace _source_dirs_ and _destination_dir_ with your directories):

```
FOR /D %p IN ("_source_dirs_*") DO MOVE %p _destination_dir_
```

Answer (score 1):

Got It! My syntax was wrong: the space was blocking the command from running. Also, I did not have User specified in the path.

After changes:

```
move C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\TZClock C:\Users\%USERNAME%\"Start Menu"\Programs\
```