# Moving ALL nested folders in many directories one level (Dos/Windows)

Tags: windows, move, subdirectory

On my "D:\" drive in Windows 7 I have a directory named "Downloads"

In this folder I have about 1400 folders with all kinds of funky/weird names with no real common denominator between them. What they do have in common is that they ALL contain one directory that has file contents.

Is there ANY way to either delete the root directories of those 1400 or so folders leaving only the subs (I need the one nested folder in there to remain intact name and content wise) OR is there any way to move every sub folder in those many directories just into "D:\Downloads" ? (I can shift select the 1400 useless directories and use the delete key afterwards.)

I'm slamming my face against the desk trying to figure this one out. Its going to take me DAYS to cut/paste all those little nested goobers into the downloads folder. I have VERY little programming experience (Basic on the TI-99/4A was as far as I got)

Thanks so much guys!

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this. For instance [check this out][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22092943/2981535

Comment: That's awesome, however my problem is quite different. If I wildcard my root directory (downloads) I can't specifically target the one nested folder inside of each of the 1400 directories in downloads - moving ONLY that one nested folder to a different location... Keep in mind EVERY single folder including the nested ones has a unique name with nothing in common.

Answer (score 1):

Crazy solution. Did a wildcard search in the downloads folder and sorted results by directory - was able to cut/paste all (1408) of the nested folders into the root!