# command prompt: how would you move subfolders to parent folder?

Tags: command, prompt

I want to move whole folders instead of files inside the subfolder. I tried MOVE command but I can only move files. Is there any other command?

Comment: Can you post an example of what command you tried?

Comment: My OS is window 7. Using command prompt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606398/command-prompt-how-would-you-move-a-folder-with-contents-from-the-desktop-to

Comment: Yes, previously I was referring to this question and answer to solve my problem. However, I only managed to move files (words, excel, text, etc). I need to move subfolder with contents.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Windows:

You may need to move the contents of the folder to another folder:

To move one or more files:
MOVE [/Y | /-Y] [drive:][path]filename1[,...] destination

example:

```
move c:\windows\temp\*.* c:\temp
```

Move the files of c:\windows\temp to the temp directory in root, this is of course assuming you have the Windows\temp directory. In this example, *.* is wildcards telling the computer every file with every extension.

Source: http://www.computerhope.com/movehlp.htm

Alternately, this SO question's answers may help you: [Command Prompt: Why do I get “cannot find the path specified” when I move a folder (with contents) from the desktop to a new directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606398/command-prompt-how-would-you-move-a-folder-with-contents-from-the-desktop-to)